# Converting Letters into Numbers for Creating an Authenticator

Tags: authentication

In Section 2.2 of DJB's *Polynomial Evaluation and Message Authentication*, he describes the construction of the first provably secure authenticator, which was the work of Gilbert, MacWilliams, and Sloane.

> Fix a finite field $k$. The legitimate sender generates 9 independent
> uniform random secrets $r1, r2, . . . , r8, s ∈ k$. The sender meets
> the legitimate receiver in private and tells the receiver the same
> secrets $r1, r2, . . . , r8, s$. Later the sender wants to send a
> message $m$ to the receiver through a public network, where $m$ is a
> sequence of 8 components $m1, m2, . . . , m8 ∈ k$. The sender
> transmits $m$ together with the authenticator $a=m1r1+···+m8r8+s ∈ k$.

Fine.  Let's say the entire message looks like this:

> sorry mrjoh nsony ourf light hasbe encan celed

This message is conveniently broken into a sequence of eight components.

**What I cannot figure out is the simple question of how to represent the letters/blocks numerically for the computations shown above.**

What is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way?

Well, any way to convert the string into values (and in a way that two different strings will never encode to the same set of values) will work, and so I don't know if there is a distinguished 'best'.

One simple way would be to take the ASCII values of each component, and interpret it as an integer (actually, an element within $k$).  For example, the string "sorry" is, in ASCII, the values 0x73, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x72, 0x79), and so you just concatinate them into a single value 0x736f727279 = 495791010425; there's your value

Comment: The paper suggests cardinality of $k \approx 2^{128}$. Wouldn't that mean that more operations are required on $m$ if it partitions into pieces longer than 16 characters each? Some sort of modulus then?

Comment: @PaulUszak: if $k \approx 2^{128}$, then 8 components total to about 128 characters.  If you need to authenticate something longer than that, then you wouldn't want to do a modulus (that'd make it easy to find a second message that would map to the exact same components); you'd want to do some sort of (collision resistant) hash or XOF.  That would mean that you're no longer "provably secure" (you would add in the assumption of collision resistance), however (without increasing $k$ or the number of secrets), about anything you do would mean you're no longer informationally secure

Answer (score 1):

[Normalize](https://www.unicode.org/faq/normalization.html) the input and encode it using [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). That gets you octet strings. Then the particular block size depends on the system you're using. For Poly1305, treat 16-byte long octet strings as little-endian integers. RFC8439 provides the way to convert a message composed of bytes into appropriately sized blocks (for Poly1305, other such systems need different sizes):

> o ...divide the message into 16-byte blocks.  The last one might be shorter:

> o  Read the block as a little-endian number.

> o  Add one bit beyond the number of octets.  For a 16-byte block, this is equivalent to adding 2^128 to the number.  For the shorter block, it can be 2^120, 2^112, or any power of two that is evenly divisible by 8, all the way down to 2^8.

> o  If the block is not 17 bytes long (the last block), pad it with zeros.  This is meaningless if you are treating the blocks as numbers.